# Automatic time on Nexus 5X says it's 2017 already, one day ahead

Tags: clock, nexus-5x, date-and-time

This morning I woke up to my phone, a Nexus 5X, telling me that it was already 2017, by saying the date was 1 January 2017. The time was/is still correct to the second, but it is only one day ahead.

My girlfriend had the same issue on her Nexus 5 this morning. Is there more people with the same problem? Can this be fixed or should it be reported?

EDIT: The problem was automatically resolved when I tried a day later

Comment: maybe this can  help you: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/calendar/Bhm8y5gXsw0

Comment: Not really. The problem is that, on automatic time, my phone tells me it is January 1st. I've now manually set the date to December 31, but reverting back to automatic date and time, switches my phone back into 2017

Comment: check the timezone, please

Comment: if that doesn't help, see this link: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/nexus/lchcdN5boRI

Comment: The timezone is correct, GMT+1, CET, so the first link in your link doesn't provide a solution. The Time Calibrator app in your link provides me the correct date, but my phone keeps the wrong date.

Comment: Hmm, this might take some research. Would you mind sending me a quick email at yisrimark@gmail.com?

Answer (score 1):

I was just reading this article:

http://android.wonderhowto.com/how-to/set-your-android-atomic-time-for-perfectly-synced-clock-0170500/

It suggests your phone is using the NITZ service to sync time, which relies on good carrier service.

The article says that if this service is bad, it might take your phone out of properly synced time.

You can try installing the suggested app.

Without root, you won't be able to sync automatically, but you can sync manually every week or so.

Comment: I expect there is no problem with my carrier service, eg. I'm in an urban area with full reception. I'm therefore bound to believe the problem is somewhere deeper than on the NITZ-connection to my phone. I will temporarily solve the problem by using the app you suggest